# (QUERY) UPDATE data into MYSQL by using Arduino SQL connector

Tags: mysql, arduino

How to write the update query by using Arduino code in order to update (overwrite) the previous data in MYSQL.

Below is the example for FIXED VALUE QUERY. Its work well but how to change to variable value?

char UPDATE_SQL[] = "update [tableName] set [column_name] = [new_fixed_value] where [column_name] = [previous value] ;

Answer (score 0):

update[database] it's wrong. It should be update[tableName]. For an example If I want to change in students table student sam's marks to 90 I can write as below

```
UPDATE students SET marks=90
WHERE name='sam'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. Yes..you are right , is update[tableName]..How to do if i want the marks as a variable and not only = 90.

Comment: Then replace 90 to your variable name

Answer (score 0):

Use **sprintf** to put your value into the string like this:

```
sprintf(UPDATE_SQL,"UPDATE students SET marks=%d WHERE name='%s'",
yourval,yourstrin);
```

Comment: I get this error (cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class String' through '...') may i know what is the problem? thanks

Comment: I found that if the variable is integer the function work well, but is the variable is string, will get the error i show above